# Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path

Tags: hadoop

I am getting the following error while starting namenode for latest hadoop-2.2 release. I didn't find winutils exe  file in hadoop bin folder. I tried below commands

```
$ bin/hdfs namenode -format
$ sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager

ERROR [main] util.Shell (Shell.java:getWinUtilsPath(303)) - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:863)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630019/running-apache-hadoop-2-1-0-on-windows

Comment: Trying to get rid of that error message I set -Dhadoop.home.dir to a meaningful value.
Now I am getting something like (local path replaced by variable name): Could not locate executable ${HADOOP_HOME}\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries. And guess what: Setting the variable did not make that binary appear. Also the priority ERROR is wrong, as the application seems to continue. In my eyes that is a bug in Hadoop 2.2.0.

Comment: There is a (as per today open) jira for this> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10051

Comment: There is a [HADOOP-11003](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11003).

Comment: Please accept answer given by Prasad D. He has provided readymade files to be used; thus avoiding efforts.

Comment: It's partially duplicate of my answer. Both download and source are links of my blog as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: That's a known Hadoop bug with Windows OS. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2356

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html

Answer (score 106):

Simple Solution:
Download it from [here](https://github.com/srccodes/hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin/archive/master.zip) and add to `$HADOOP_HOME/bin`

([Source](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/39/error-util-shell-failed-locate-winutils-binary-hadoop-binary-path))

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**

For **hadoop-2.6.0** you can download binaries from [Titus Barik blog >>](http://www.barik.net/archive/2015/01/19/172716/).

I have not only needed to point `HADOOP_HOME` to extracted directory `[path]`, but also provide system property `-Djava.library.path=[path]\bin` to load native libs (dll).

Comment: This helps to start the hdfs but when I try to put a text file into hdfs it gives error   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.nativeComputeChunkedSumsBy
teArray(II[BI[BIILjava/lang/String;JZ)V

Comment: It's partially duplicate of my answer. Both download and source are links of my blog as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: This appears to work with Hadoop 2.7.3 as well.  Or is would there be an issue? 1) download from the page above. tar xfvz which gives a Hadoop 2.6 distribution.  Then copy bin\winutlis.exe to the 2.73 \bin directory.  Instantly, it works.  So far - at least.

Answer (score 29):

If you face this problem when running a self-contained local application with Spark (i.e., after adding spark-assembly-x.x.x-hadoopx.x.x.jar or the Maven dependency to the project), a simpler solution would be to put winutils.exe (download from [here](https://github.com/srccodes/hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin/archive/master.zip)) in "C:\winutil\bin". Then you can add winutils.exe to the hadoop home directory by adding the following line to the code:

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c:\\\winutil\\\")
```

Source: Click [here](http://nanxiao.me/en/build-apache-spark-application-in-intellij-idea-14-1/)

Comment: For me it was enough to put the winutils stuff in `hadoop/bin/bin/`. So just copy the winutils `bin` folder in hadoop's `bin` folder. (`HADOOP_HOME` is set in the env vars)

Comment: +1 There is one too many slash in the directory path, so I'm leaving this here for myself: `System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c:\\winutil\\")`

Answer (score 27):

If we directly take the binary distribution of Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 release and try to run it on Microsoft Windows, then we'll encounter ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path.

The binary distribution of Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 release does not contain some windows native components (like winutils.exe, hadoop.dll etc). These are required (not optional) to run Hadoop on Windows.

So you need to build windows native binary distribution of hadoop from source codes following "BUILD.txt" file located inside the source distribution of hadoop. You can follow the following posts as well for step by step guide with screen shot

[Build, Install, Configure and Run Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 in Microsoft Windows OS](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os)

[ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/39/error-util-shell-failed-locate-winutils-binary-hadoop-binary-path)

Comment: Hi Abhijit. Have you followed your own directions? Hadoop is not supported on Windows.  Actually it is only supported on certain versions of Windows Server.  That is very lousy by Microsoft and HortonWorks.

Comment: That was over two years ago and very (very!) true at the time. I had verified directly with Hortonworks engineers just two weeks prior at a conference.

Answer (score 21):

Winutils.exe is used for running the shell commands for SPARK. 
When you need to run the Spark without installing Hadoop, you need this file.

Steps are as follows:

1. Download the winutils.exe from following location for hadoop 2.7.1
   https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin
   [NOTE: If you are using separate hadoop version then please download the winutils from corresponding hadoop version folder on GITHUB from the location as mentioned above.]
2. Now, create a folder 'winutils' in C:\ drive. Now create a folder 'bin' inside folder 'winutils' and copy the winutils.exe in that folder. 
   So the location of winutils.exe will be **C:\winutils\bin\winutils.exe**
3. Now, open environment variable and set HADOOP_HOME=C:\winutils
   [NOTE: **Please do not add** **\bin** in **HADOOP_HOME** and no need to set HADOOP_HOME in Path]

Your issue must be resolved !!

Answer (score 19):

The statement
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe

explains that the null is received when expanding or replacing an Environment Variable. If you see the Source in Shell.Java in Common Package you will find that HADOOP_HOME variable is not getting set and you are receiving null in place of that and hence the error.

So, HADOOP_HOME needs to be set for this properly or the variable hadoop.home.dir property.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Kamleshwar.

Comment: On which configuration file we need to set hadoop.home.dir property (Ex. hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml ) ?

Comment: System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutil\\");  
reference : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33610936/3110474

Comment: If you're using Windows, make sure you use double backslashes while writing any path as a value.

Answer (score 13):

I just ran into this issue while working with Eclipse. In my case, I had the correct Hadoop version downloaded (hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0.tgz), I extracted the contents and placed it directly in my C drive. Then I went to

Eclipse->Debug/Run Configurations -> Environment (tab) -> and added

variable: HADOOP_HOME

Value: C:\hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0

Answer (score 8):

You can download winutils.exe here: 
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-win-alpha/winutils.exe

Then copy it to your `HADOOP_HOME/bin` directory.

Comment: In case the link didn't work, you can also download it from here:
https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/releases

Answer (score 4):

In Pyspark, to run local spark application using Pycharm use below lines

```
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "C:\\winutils"
print os.environ['HADOOP_HOME']
```

Answer (score 3):

winutils.exe are required  for hadoop to perform hadoop related commands. please download 
hadoop-common-2.2.0 zip file. winutils.exe can be found in  bin folder. Extract the zip file and copy it in the local hadoop/bin folder.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem. Removing the `bin\` from the HADOOP_HOME path solved it for me. The path for HADOOP_HOME variable should look something like.

```
C:\dev\hadoop2.6\
```

System restart may be needed. In my case, restarting the IDE was sufficient.

Comment: Thank you @Asmat Ali, restart of IDE was the part i was missing.

Answer (score 3):

As most answers here refer to pretty old versions of winutils, I will leave a link to the most comprehensive repository, which supports all versions of Hadoop including the most recent ones:

https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils
(find the directory corresponding to your Hadoop version, or try the most recent one).

**If you have admin permissions on you machine.**

1. Put `bin` directory into `C:\winutils`
   The whole path should be `C:\winutils\bin\winutils.exe`
2. Set `HADOOP_HOME` into `C:\winutils`

**If you don't have admin permissions or want to put the binaries into user space.**

1. Put `bin` directory into `C:\Users\vryabtse\AppData\Local\Programs\winutils` or similar user directory.
2. Set `HADOOP_HOME` value into path to this directory.

Answer (score 2):

Set up **HADOOP_HOME** variable in windows to resolve the problem.

You can find answer in `org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.2.0/hadoop-common-2.2.0-sources.jar!/org/apache/hadoop/util/Shell.java` :

IOException from

```
  public static final String getQualifiedBinPath(String executable) 
  throws IOException {
    // construct hadoop bin path to the specified executable
    String fullExeName = HADOOP_HOME_DIR + File.separator + "bin" 
      + File.separator + executable;
    File exeFile = new File(fullExeName);
    if (!exeFile.exists()) {
      throw new IOException("Could not locate executable " + fullExeName
        + " in the Hadoop binaries.");
    }
    return exeFile.getCanonicalPath();
  }
```

HADOOP_HOME_DIR from

```
// first check the Dflag hadoop.home.dir with JVM scope
String home = System.getProperty("hadoop.home.dir");
// fall back to the system/user-global env variable
if (home == null) {
  home = System.getenv("HADOOP_HOME");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Download desired version of hadoop folder (Say if you are installing spark on Windows then hadoop version for which your spark is built for) from [this](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils) link as zip.

Extract the zip to desired directory.
You need to have directory of the form `hadoop\bin` (explicitly create such `hadoop\bin` directory structure if you want) with `bin` containing all the files contained in `bin` folder of the downloaded hadoop. This will contain many files such as hdfs.dll, hadoop.dll etc. in addition to winutil.exe.

Now [create environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) `HADOOP_HOME` and set it to `<path-to-hadoop-folder>\hadoop`. Then [add](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) `;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin;` to `PATH` environment variable.

Open a "new command prompt" and try rerunning your command.

Comment: this worked for me, and the alternative with HADOOP_HOME pointing to the bin directory (rather than it's parent) did not.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [winutils.exe] 

    
   From URL :

   https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/hadoop-*`version`*/bin
2. Past it under HADOOP_HOME/bin

   ***Note : You should Set environmental variables:***

   **User variable:**

   **Variable**: HADOOP_HOME

   **Value**: Hadoop or spark dir

Answer (score 1):

I used "hbase-1.3.0" and "hadoop-2.7.3" versions. Setting HADOOP_HOME environment variable and copying 'winutils.exe' file under HADOOP_HOME/bin folder solves the problem on a windows os.
Attention to set HADOOP_HOME environment to the installation folder of hadoop(/bin folder is not necessary for these versions).
Additionally I preferred using cross platform tool [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to settle linux os functionality (as possible as it can) because Hbase team recommend linux/unix env.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue in windows. I fixed it by

- Downloading hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master from [link](https://github.com/srccodes/hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin/archive/master.zip).
- Create a user variable HADOOP_HOME in Environment variable and assign the path of hadoop-common bin directory as a value.
- You can verify it by running hadoop in cmd.
- Restart the IDE and Run it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got the same error message while running spark application on Intellij Idea. What I did was, I downloaded the winutils.exe that is compatible with the Spark version I was running and moved it to the Spark bin directory. Then in my Intellij, I edited the configuration.

The 'Environment variables' area was empty. So, I entered `HADOOP_HOME = P:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7`
Since, the winutils.exe is in the `P:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\bin` directory, it will locate the file while running.

So, by setting HADOOP_HOME, the null would be the HADOOP_HOME directory. Complete path would be `P:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\winutils.exe`
That was how I resolved it