# Configuring hadoop 2.5 in eclipse

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to configure map-reduce in eclipse indigo with hadoop version 2.5. I downloaded hadoop 2.5 source and added all the libraries in the eclipse project.

While trying to run the project, it is showing following error[image: error showing in eclipse]

Java path and classpath was set properly. Please help me.!!

Configuring cygiwn SSH is mandatory to use eclipse map-reduce?

Comment: In windows, It is mandatory to configure `cygiwn` for compatiablity and `SSH` which enables daemons to communicate each other.

Comment: i configured ssh in cygwin,but no luck.Again the same error..!

Comment: By looking at the stacktrace of the error, [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620642/failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path) will help you..!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here. If you are running the application in eclipse as a regular traditional java program the following may help.

Hadoop map reduce programs must run the program using the hadoop jar command usually after using SSH ( PuTTY ) onto the cluster and using TFTP ( FileZila ) to port the .jar file to the cluster.

```
Usage: hadoop jar <jar> [mainClass] args…
```

If you want to debug the application use `java.util.logging.Logger`.