# Getting NoSuchMethodError when setting up Spark GraphX graph

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm getting a similar error to the one encountered [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/GraphX-java-lang-NoSuchMethodError-org-apache-spark-graphx-Graph-apply-td19958.html) - I can run GraphX using the spark shell, but I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError when I try to use spark-submit on a jar file. This is the line that it complains about:

```
val myGraph: Graph[(String, Long, String), Int] = Graph.apply(userRecords, userConnectionEdges)
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.graphx.
Graph$.apply$default$4()Lorg/apache/spark/storage/StorageLevel;
        at MyProject$.main(MyProject.scala:53)
        at MyProject.main(MyProject.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:292)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

The code builds using sbt assembly, so I'm not what is going wrong.

EDIT: I created a new scala project to take the code from [here](https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/graph-analytics-with-graphx.html) and built it into a jar file. This is the scala file:

```
/* GraphTest.scala */

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object GraphTest {

 def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Set up environment
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // Set up the vertices
    val vertexArray = Array(
      (1L, ("Alice", 28)),
      (2L, ("Bob", 27)),
      (3L, ("Charlie", 65)),
      (4L, ("David", 42)),
      (5L, ("Ed", 55)),
      (6L, ("Fran", 50))
      )

    // Set up the edges
    val edgeArray = Array(
      Edge(2L, 1L, 7),
      Edge(2L, 4L, 2),
      Edge(3L, 2L, 4),
      Edge(3L, 6L, 3),
      Edge(4L, 1L, 1),
      Edge(5L, 2L, 2),
      Edge(5L, 3L, 8),
      Edge(5L, 6L, 3)
      )

    // Convert arrays to RDDs
    val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, (String, Int))] = sc.parallelize(vertexArray)
    val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Int]] = sc.parallelize(edgeArray)

    // Create graph and print vertex data
    val graph: Graph[(String, Int), Int] = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)

    graph.vertices.filter { case (id, (name, age)) => age > 30 }.collect.foreach {
        case (id, (name, age)) => println(s"$name is $age")
    } 
 } 
}
```

Here are the build settings:

```
import AssemblyKeys._

assemblySettings

name := "graphtest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.10" % "1.2.1" % "provided"
```

I can run sbt assembly on the code, but when I run

```
..\spark\bin\spark-submit --class GraphTest target\scala-2.10\graphtest-assembly-1.0.jar
```

I get the NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Maybe a version mismatch?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem.  I entered the code from previous submission and it worked just fine.  I was also able to create a Graph explicitly invoking apply (rather than just `Graph(vertices, edges)`) as you are doing, without any errors.  The only difference I can see is that I started by importing import org.apache.spark.graphx._ into my REPL session.  Can you post a full REPL session that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a version issue - I was using the SBT and Spark from the Databricks training, which are a few versions behind the current version. This will work with the latest version of SBT (v0.13.7), Scala (2.10.4), and Spark (1.2.1).

After I got that working, I encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620642/failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path) Spark/Hadoop/winutils.exe error. Eventually I got it all working :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding a dependency for graphx only, rather than Spark as a whole; eg `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.1" % "provided"`.

Comment: Added that to the build file, but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's probably your use of the "[provided](http://pythonhackers.com/p/rjmac/sbt-assembly)" dependencies: "To exclude some jar file, first consider using "provided" dependency".  I'm guessing they're not part of your assembly, and thus not getting deployed when you invoke `spark-submit`.

Comment: I have "addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")" in the project/plugins.sbt file. Is there something else I should add?

Comment: It has to be something that is specific to the Graph class, since I can use the Edge class without a problem.