# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream with Spark on local mode

Tags: scala, maven, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have used Spark before in yarn-cluster mode and it's been good so far.

However, I wanted to run it "local" mode, so I created a simple scala app, added spark as dependency via maven and then tried to run the app like a normal application.

However, I get the above exception in the very first line where I try to create a SparkConf object.

I don't understand, why I need hadoop to run a standalone spark app. Could someone point out what's going on here.

My two line app:

```
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("MLPipeline.AutomatedBinner")//.set("spark.default.parallelism", "300").set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb", "256").set("spark.akka.frameSize", "256").set("spark.akka.timeout", "1000") //.set("spark.akka.threads", "300")//.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") //.set("spark.akka.timeout", "1000")
 val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

Comment: see this link for an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906412/noclassdeffounderror-com-apache-hadoop-fs-fsdatainputstream-when-execute-spark-s

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906412/noclassdeffounderror-com-apache-hadoop-fs-fsdatainputstream-when-execute-spark-s this mat help you!