# multiple version of spark on CDH5.10 is failing to launch spark-submit

Tags: cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have installed spark with 2.0 on CDH5.10 By following the link https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark2_installing.html

after all configuration when I hit spark2-submit --version it gives me correct version which is 2.0

however when I submit a spark job . First it says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
```

This is clearly indicating that hadoop libs are not in classpath. My question is  it something wrong with my installation of spark 2. ? also once we add jars with sparkExtralibCLasspath for driver and core then it says SPARK_HADOOP_CONF Is not set. 
How can I verify my installation is correct ?
I am also trying to understand where are my spark2 conf dirs
I saw few previous question on stackoverflow like https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/CHD-5-7-spark-shell-java-lang-ClassNotFoundException-org-apache/td-p/42209  and [NoClassDefFoundError com.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream when execute spark-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906412/noclassdeffounderror-com-apache-hadoop-fs-fsdatainputstream-when-execute-spark-s) but this doesnt help

I am using spark2-shell and spark2-submit command

some more investigation with https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/CDH-5-5-pyspark-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-org-apache-hadoop/td-p/34424 shows might be If I can correctly set SPARK_EXTRA_LIB_PATH for spark2 then I can fix this issue. can somebody guide me please. Thanks