# Write RDD as textfile using Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am exploring Spark for batch processing. I am running the spark on my local machine using standalone mode.

I am trying to convert the Spark RDD as single file [final output] using saveTextFile() method, but its not working.

For example if i have more than one partition how we can get one single file as final output.

**Update:**

I tried the below approaches, but i am getting null pointer exception.

```
person.coalesce(1).toJavaRDD().saveAsTextFile("C://Java_All//output");
person.repartition(1).toJavaRDD().saveAsTextFile("C://Java_All//output");
```

The exception is :

```
    15/06/23 18:25:27 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
15/06/23 18:25:27 INFO deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
15/06/23 18:25:27 INFO deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
15/06/23 18:25:27 INFO deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
15/06/23 18:25:27 INFO deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
15/06/23 18:25:27 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1104)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/06/23 18:25:27 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1104)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15/06/23 18:25:27 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/06/23 18:25:27 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/06/23 18:25:27 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 1
15/06/23 18:25:27 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (saveAsTextFile at TestSpark.java:40) failed in 0.249 s
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: saveAsTextFile at TestSpark.java:40, took 0.952286 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1104)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.37.145.179:4040
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO Utils: path = C:\Users\crh537\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-a52371d8-ae6a-4567-b759-0a6c66c1908c\blockmgr-4d17a5b4-c8f8-4408-af07-0e88239794e8, already present as root for deletion.
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
15/06/23 18:25:28 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: well your rdd is getting empty somewhere. we can't help you find the error with the portion of code you have given us.. i advise you to try at least to count your rdd check if it's empty and do it one by one!

Comment: Can you check for your FileSystem or HDFS permissions for that particular folder. Also you can append the protocol before the Filesystem Path. Also as mentioned previously you may need to set WinUtils in your System path If you want to run hadoop related things on your Local.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` method to save into a single file. This way your code will look like this:

```
val myFile = sc.textFile("file.txt")
val finalRdd = doStuff(myFile)
finalRdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("newfile")
```

There is also another method `repartition` to do the same thing, however it will cause a shuffle which is may be very expensive, while coalesce will try to avoid a shuffle.

Comment: i am using Java to implement Spark, but i am getting the exception, i have updated the question with exception details.

Comment: Looks like it is trying to write file and it fails. Can you check if you have permissions to write to directory?
Also, since Spark is lazy, it may be that the problem is in person rdd. Can you run `person.coalesce(1).toJavaRDD().count()` to make sure that it produces a number of lines and does not throw the exception?

Comment: when i use saveAsTextFile("") where it will save the file , i mean which node (worker or driver). Also can we give any specific file name as output file?

Comment: Normally you would not save to workers or drivers specifically unless using locally. In a distributed cluster environment you would normally would save to either HDFS, s3 or some other store.
Examples:
 - S3:      rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3n://bucketname/path/newfile.csv")
 - HDFS: rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://path/newfile.csv")

Answer (score 11):

Are you running this on windows? if yes, then you need to add the following line

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutil\\")
```

You can down load the winutils from the following link

http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-win-alpha/winutils.exe

Answer (score 0):

Spark internally uses hadoop file system so when you try to read and write on to filesytem it will first look for HADOOP_HOME configuration folder that contains bin\winutils.exe. may be you doesn't set this thats the reason its throwing nullpointer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use repartition method in RDD. It actually creates as many partitions as you passed integer to it. In your case it will be :

```
rdd.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("path to save rdd")
```

Comment: i am using Java to implement Spark, but i am getting the exception, i have updated the question with exception details.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download winutils.exe
2. Place winutils.exe under the bin folder of any drive(D:/Winutils/bin/)
3. Set the path in your code as below

   System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\Winutils\\");

Now run your code, it has to work.