# Scala & Spark: Dataframe.write._ on Windows

Tags: windows, scala, csv, apache-spark

Did somebody manage to write files (and especially CSV) using Spark's [DataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) on Windows?

Many answers on SO are outdated (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674530/write-single-csv-file-using-spark-csv)) because of Sparks native capabilities to write .CSV (and a unified `write()` method) since version 2.0. Also, I downloaded and added `winutils.exe` like proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993655/write-rdd-as-textfile-using-apache-spark).

**Code**:

```
// reading works just fine
val df = spark.read
             .option("header", true)
             .option("inferSchema", true)
             .csv("file:///C:/tmp/in.csv")
// writing fails, none of these work
df.write.csv("file:///C:/tmp/out.csv")
df.write.csv("C:/tmp/out.csv")
```

**Error**:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:551)
    at prost.ebtl.load.DataSourceCSV$.loadFromFilesystem(DataSourceCSV.scala:12)
    at TestScala$$anonfun$main$2.apply(TestScala.scala:98)
    at TestScala$$anonfun$main$2.apply(TestScala.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at TestScala$.main(TestScala.scala:80)
    at TestScala.main(TestScala.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 13, 192.168.56.1): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:890)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVRelation.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOutputWriterFactory.newInstance(CSVRelation.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1904)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:890)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVRelation.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOutputWriterFactory.newInstance(CSVRelation.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Note**: A folder named `out.csv` is created though

**Setup**: Hadoop v.2.7.3, Spark 2.0.1 Intelli J IDEA 2016.2, Scala 2.11.8, Testcluster on Win7 Workstation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this, its working. You need to set warehouse dir configuration. That's the only thing missing from your code,also do you have write access to the directory where you are trying to write.

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Spark SQL CSV example")
    .master("local")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/IJava/")
    .getOrCreate()

  val df = spark.read
    .option("header", true)
    .option("inferSchema", true)
    .csv("file:///C:/Users/sankar/Downloads/FLinsurancesample.csv")

  df.write.csv("file:///C:/Users/sankar/Downloads/out.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks ! Wohooo, that why I like stack overflow. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Your answer solves the issue, when running with `master("local[2]")` but not with a `spark://` URL. I guess that is up to windows. I guess I'll wait until I'm on Mac. Thanks!