# SparkR from Rstudio - gives Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) :

Tags: r, apache-spark, hiveql, apache-spark-mllib, sparkr

I am using RStudio.

After creating session if i try to create dataframe using R data it gives error.

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "E:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME = "E:/winutils")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"sparkr-shell"')

library(SparkR)

sparkR.session(sparkConfig = list(spark.sql.warehouse.dir="C:/Temp"))

localDF <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Smith", "Sarah"), age=c(19, 23, 18))
df <- createDataFrame(localDF)
```

ERROR :

```
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog(HiveSharedState.scala:45)
    at org.a
>
```

TIA.

[image]

Comment: I am using prebuilt spark2.0.0 on windows 8

Comment: Thanks in advance ! @Hack-R

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME setup as explained in this post http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/04/how-to-run-apache-spark-on-windows7-in.html

Comment: Hi @abhiieor thanks , yep i have a configured JAVA_HOME . I also followed the blog and executed spark sample program works fine ( giving correct output-3.14) so this means local spark set up in standalone mode is fine. I am trying SparkR on Rstudio for POC. Any pointers on this ?

Comment: Did you try to set the Spark session as explained here? https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/sparkr.html#starting-up-from-rstudio

Comment: hi @JaimeCr yep, tried with this also. infact SparkSession get created like -  "Java ref type org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession id 1 "  . Session gets created from command prompt also, by that i mean if i execute the SparkR from command prompt from spark home directory. while executing r code system hangs though.

Comment: $hive.metastore.warehouse.dir
[1] "file:C:\\Users\\Nineteen\\Documents/spark-warehouse"

$spark.app.name
[1] "SparkR"

$spark.driver.memory
[1] "1g"

$spark.driver.port
[1] "49676"

$spark.executor.id
[1] "driver"

$spark.executorEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH
[1] "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"

$spark.home
[1] "E:\\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7"

$spark.master
[1] "local[*]"

$spark.sql.catalogImplementation
[1] "hive"

$spark.sql.warehouse.dir
[1] "/file:C:\\temp"

$spark.submit.deployMode
[1] "client"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not used SparkR library but you're using Spark,
I recommend 'sparklyr' library made by RStudio.

1. Install the preview version of RStudio.
2. Install the library:

   ```
   install.packages("devtools")
   devtools::install_github('rstudio/sparklyr')
   ```
3. Load library and install spark.

   ```
   library(sparklyr)
   spark_install('1.6.2')
   ```

You can see a vignette in http://spark.rstudio.com/

Comment: but this is for 1.6.1 version right ? will it work for spark 2.0.0 ? Also i wanted to make use of SparkML component for my POC and subsequently usage in actual analysis. In parallel I will check the sparklyr

Answer (score 5):

All many thanks for your help.

1. I had to do was set hadoop_home path in PATH variables
   (winutils/bin). This should have your winutils.exe file. So when it
   creates metastore for hive default derby) it is able to call hive
   classes.
2. Also i had set hive support as False as i am not using it.

---

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='E:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7',HADOOP_HOME='E:/winutils')

.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R', 'lib'),.libPaths()))

Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"sparkr-shell"')

library(SparkR)
library(rJava)

sparkR.session(enableHiveSupport = FALSE,master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "1g",spark.sql.warehouse.dir="E:/winutils/bin/"))

df <- as.DataFrame(iris)
```

Comment: I am having the same error, and unfortunately, these fixes don't still solve the problem. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Also for me disabling Hive support switch solved the issue . No other change from default was needed.  Not sure how general this a solution is.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps that I did in RStudio and it worked for me:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="C:\\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))

library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

localDF <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Smith", "Sarah"), age=c(19, 23, 18))
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, localDF)
```