# Creating data frames in SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am new here....so sorry if I ask naive questions !!!

I am using SparkR in Rstudio.

R version 3.3.2
Spark version 2.0.2

I am able to successfully launch Spark in R studio and I can see using webUI. localhost:4040 that my spark is up and running.

But once I try to create data frame it gives error something like this:

```
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:474)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:488)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:480)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:7
```

Can anybody help me with this....Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe this previous question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863003/sparkr-from-rstudio-gives-error-in-invokejavaisstatic-true-classname-meth

Comment: When you use sparkR, you can't work with normal dataframe. You need to work with SparkDataFrame you can check this https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#sparkdataframe

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys. I was missing one file, which can be downloaded from git, here is link: https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin

Actually one of my friends also had same problem, just add this file and it should work fine.