# (null) entry in command string exception in saveAsTextFile() on Pyspark

Tags: windows, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am working in PySpark on a Jupyter notebook (Python 2.7) in windows 7. I have an RDD of type `pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD` called `idSums`. When attempting to execute `idSums.saveAsTextFile("Output")`, I receive the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o834.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 33.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 33.0 (TID 131, localhost): java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\Users\seride\Desktop\Experiments\PySpark\Output\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_201611231307_0033_m_000001_131\part-00001
```

There shouldn't be any problem with the RDD object, in my opinion, because I'm able to execute other actions without error, e.g. executing `idSums.collect()` produces the correct output.

Furthermore, the `Output` directory is created (with all subdirectories) and the file `part-00001` is created, but it is 0 bytes.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are missing  [`winutils.exe`](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)  a hadoop binary . Depending upon x64 bit / x32 bit  System download the [`winutils.exe`](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils) file & set your hadoop home pointing to it.

1st way :

1. Download the file
2. Create `hadoop` folder in Your System, ex `C:`
3. Create `bin` folder in `hadoop` directory, ex : `C:\hadoop\bin`
4. paste `winutils.exe` in `bin`, ex: `C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe`
5. In User Variables in System Properties -> Advance System Settings

Create New Variable
Name: `HADOOP_HOME`
Path: `C:\hadoop\`

2nd Way :

You can set hadoop home directly in Your Java Program with the following Command like this :

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C:\hadoop" );
```

Comment: This solution works. Thank you! Note that while spark can run without hadoop (as you know @HapreetVarma), it runs with reduced functionality.

Comment: 2nd way works fine and able to locate winutils.exe, But getting new error "ExitCodeException exitCode=1: ChangeFileModeByMask error (5): Access is denied". Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: But why does Spark need 'winutils.exe'? Any leads guys?

Comment: @DineshKumarP  if you set it up on windows then you would need it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar exception saying permission issue when loading a model built in some other machine and copied in my Windows system although my `HADOOP_HOME` was set.

I just ran the following command over my model folder:

```
winutils.exe chmod -R 777 model-path
```

Answer (score 0):

Same procedure as describe above by @Hapreet Varma

You are missing winutils.exe a hadoop binary . Depending upon x64 bit / x32 bit System download the winutils.exe file & set your hadoop home pointing to it .

1st way :

1.Download the file

2.Create hadoop folder in Your System ex " C:"

3.Create bin folder in hadoop directory ex : C:\hadoop\bin

4.paste winutils.exe in bin ex: C:\hadoop\bin\winuitls.exe

5.In User Variables in System Properties -> Advance System Settings

Create New Variable Name: HADOOP_HOME Path: C:\hadoop\

2nd Way :

You can set hadoop home directly in Your Java Program with the following Command like this :

System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C:\hadoop" );

**if you are working in Eclipse Oxygen than you must restart the Eclipse after setting the variable in system properties otherwise it will not work.**
In case of wrong path set Eclipse will show the current set location of winutils at the start of the log. some thing like this

**2018-05-05 18:27:47 ERROR Shell:397 - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path**

**java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.**

Full error log is here

```
2018-05-05 18:27:47 ERROR Shell:397 - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2464)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2464)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2464)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:930)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at com.dataflair.spark.Wordcount$.main(Wordcount.scala:13)
    at com.dataflair.spark.Wordcount.main(Wordcount.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found additional information that may help others fix this issue. Sometimes when you set up spark on a windows machine you fail to get the hadoop.dll file. Simply take the hadoop.dll file from winutils GitRepo (https://github.com/4ttty/winutils) and place it within you windows system 32 folder. After I did this, I was able to write to disk.

Original credit for this answer - https://programmersought.com/article/53121203250/

Answer (score 0):

Even after setting the bin path if it is not working then you need to close the eclipse scala ide application and open it again and try to run it .