# Spark Dataframes are getting created successfully but not able to write into the Local Disk

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I am using IntelliJ IDE for executing Spark Scala code on Microsoft Windows Platform.

I have four Spark Dataframes of around 30000 records each and I tried to take one column from each of those Dataframes as part of my requirement.

I used Spark SQL function to do it and it got executed successfully. When I execute DF.show() or DF.count() method, I am able to see results in the screen but when I tried to write the dataframe into my local disk (windows directory) the job is getting aborted with the below error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted.  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:492)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:198)
>     at main.src.countFeatures2$.countFeature$1(countFeatures2.scala:118)
>     at
>   main.src.countFeatures2$.getFeatureAsString$1(countFeatures2.scala:32)
>     at main.src.countFeatures2$.main(countFeatures2.scala:40)   at
>   main.src.countFeatures2.main(countFeatures2.scala)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage
>   failure: Task 0 in stage 31.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure:
>   Lost task 0.0 in stage 31.0 (TID 2636, localhost, executor driver):
>   java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644
>   D:\Test_Output_File2_temporary\0_temporary\attempt_20170830194047_0031_m_000000_0\part-00000-85c32c55-e12d-4433-979d-ccecb2fcd341.csv
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.(CSVRelation.scala:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOutputWriterFactory.newInstance(CSVRelation.scala:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.(FileFormatWriter.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:127)
>     ... 28 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command
>   string: null chmod 0644
>   D:\Test_Output_File2_temporary\0_temporary\attempt_20170830194047_0031_m_000000_0\part-00000-85c32c55-e12d-4433-979d-ccecb2fcd341.csv
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.(CSVRelation.scala:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOutputWriterFactory.newInstance(CSVRelation.scala:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.(FileFormatWriter.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:
>   -Xmx512M
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I am not able to understand where it went wrong. Can anybody explain how to overcome this issue ?

**UPDATE**
Please note that I was able to write the same files until yesterday and no changes were made in my system or with the IDE's configuration. So I don't understand why it was running till yesterday and why not it is running now

There was a similar post in this link : [(null) entry in command string exception in saveAsTextFile() on Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764807/null-entry-in-command-string-exception-in-saveastextfile-on-pyspark) but they are using pyspark on Jupiter notebook whereas my issue is with IntelliJ IDE

**Super simplified code that writes the output file to local disk**

```
val Test_Output =spark.sql("select A.Col1, A.Col2, B.Col2, C.Col2, D.Col2 from A, B, C, D where A.primaryKey = B.primaryKey and B.primaryKey = C.primaryKey and C.primaryKey = D.primaryKey and D.primaryKey = A.primaryKey")

val Test_Output_File = Test_Output.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("nullValue", "0").save("D:/Test_Output_File")
```

Comment: can you post your writing code as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(null) entry in command string exception in saveAsTextFile() on Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764807/null-entry-in-command-string-exception-in-saveastextfile-on-pyspark)

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40958969/647053) it should work. same solution was suggested by another answer below.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Those changes are already in place. But still it is not working. And they encountered error on Jupiter Notebook when they tried to call Spark from Python whereas I am using Spark straightaway in IntelliJ IDE

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Added the sample code for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I rectified myself. I used **.persist()** method while creating dataframes. That helped me to write the output files without any error. Though I do not understand the logic behind it.

Appreciating your valuable inputs on this

Comment: I used .persist() but, still the same file permission error "(null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644". Do we still need "winuitls.exe"?

Answer (score 3):

Seems related to filesystem:  `java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644`

Since you are running on windows, have you set your HADOOP_HOME to a folder with winutils.exe?

Comment: yes . That's why it was running successfully till yesterday. I did not make any changes to my system or to the IDE later. But now it is not writing the files.

Comment: It may sound silly.. but do you have another instance of spark running at the same time?  Sometimes, I get strange behavior when I have another unit test still running that haven't been properly shutdowned.  Aim for the `pskill java` ;)

Comment: No @pskill java . I do not have another instance