# Why does Spark application fail with "IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644"?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write the dataset results into a single CSV using below using JAVA

```
dataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header",true).csv("C:\\tmp\\csvs");
```

But it goes for timed out , the file is not being written.

Throws `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.`

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:

Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 16, localhost): java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\tmp\12333333testSpark\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_201712282255_0013_m_000000_0\part-r-00000-229fd1b6-ffb9-4ba1-9dc9-89dfdbd0be43.csv
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVRelation.scala:200)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOutputWriterFactory.newInstance(CSVRelation.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764807/null-entry-in-command-string-exception-in-saveastextfile-on-pyspark

Comment: The Output Folder is getting created, But not the file. it shows same error. :(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You might want to narrow down to fixing the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644
```

Try set `HADOOP_HOME` to the subdirectory with `bin\winutils.exe` as reported in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764807/null-entry-in-command-string-exception-in-saveastextfile-on-pyspark).  If that doesn't help, there is a work-around reported at another [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963507/spark-dataframes-are-getting-created-successfully-but-not-able-to-write-into-the).

Comment: This actually worked.  Thanks But Can you say why this is issue happens.

Comment: Apparently the issue is related to a [missing binary file for Windows](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10051) in the Hadoop bin tarball.

Comment: But I have been getting same error in EMR cluster where the spark is configured too. The exact same error.  There I can’t copy this winutils.  What can I do there ???

Comment: In that case I would suggest that you submit an [AWS support request](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=technical) to resolve the problem.