# How to read a CSV file and then save it as JSON in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a CSV file that has around 7 million rows, and 22 columns.

How to save it as a JSON file after reading the CSV in a Spark Dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Read a `CSV` file as a dataframe

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").appname("test").getOrCreate
val df = spark.read.csv("path to csv")
```

Now you can perform some operation to `df` and save as `JSON`

```
df.write.json("output path")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried to do that, but it is showing SparkException, IOException. And in error it is showing "Job is aborted while writing the rows". I don't know why. Can you help? I'm new to Spark, that is why finding it difficult to understand.

Comment: Why did not you shared what issue you faced, what you tried, can you share the error log?

Comment: ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 D:\sample.json\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20181122150723_0003_m_000000_0\part-00000-448b77ae-c17d-45fe-bba0-a6495fd5c6bd-c000.json
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:762)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:859)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:842)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:661)

Comment: did you already checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010634/why-does-spark-application-fail-with-ioexception-null-entry-in-command-strin?noredirect=1&lq=1?