# sc.textFile() gives Error while running command to get file permissions : java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

java version 1.8, spark version 2.11

I want to read some data from the directory `./data` in my spark project:

[image]

```scala
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("WordCount")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val lines = sc.textFile("datas")   // datas is a dictionary which contain some txt file
```

it comes error:

> Error while running command to get file permissions :
> java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string

that says I have no permissions to read the file in directory `./datas`.
But when I change code to read a specific document in `./datas`:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("datas/1.txt")
```

it works.

How can I read all file in `./datas` using `sc.textFile("datas")`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(null) entry in command string exception in saveAsTextFile() on Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764807/null-entry-in-command-string-exception-in-saveastextfile-on-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution：

Because Method `textFile` can only recognize specific files, I change the path to all files in the current directory `(your path)/*`.

e.g.

```scala
val lines = sc.textFile("datas/*")
```

it works.

Comment: Technically you were telling spark to read a directory called datas, when you added /* to it, you are now telling to read all files inside datas directory which is the expected behaviour.