# What is the right way to solve: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx---

Tags: apache-spark, hive, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I am working on a spark program that will load the data into Hive tables and I am doing that on Spark Version: 2.0.2
Initially I did executed these two steps on spark-shell:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("SparkHive").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition","true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode","nonstrict").config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir","/user/hive/warehouse").getOrCreate()
```

When I tried to load a dataset from HDFS into spark, I was getting an exception for the below line:

```
val partFile = spark.read.textFile("hdfs://quickstart:8020/user/cloudera/partfile")
```

Exception:

```
The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx---
```

After doing some research online, I learnt that only HDFS has the permission to work on the /tmp/hive directory and not even the root user can operate on it. I tried the below command and as predicted, it didn't work.

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive/
```

But I performed these steps and I was able to load the file into Spark.

1. In hdfs, Remove the /tmp/hive directory ==> "hdfs dfs -rm -r
   /tmp/hive"
2. At OS level too, delete the dir /tmp/hive ==> rm -rf /tmp/hive

My question is, could anyone tell me if it is this the right way to fix the issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does spark-shell fail with "The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644206/why-does-spark-shell-fail-with-the-root-scratch-dir-tmp-hive-on-hdfs-should-b)