# Apache Apex minimum development environment

Tags: hadoop, stream-processing, apache-apex

I am wondering what the minimum environment I need to develop and test my Apex apps?

Running in `Eclipse` on `Windows`, I generated `Apex` project using the Apex archtype  and tried to run the default `JUnit` test that gets created but get the following error:

> 2016-04-05 13:00:02,677 [main] DEBUG physical.PhysicalPlan
>   initCheckpoint - Writing activation checkpoint {ffffffffffffffff, 0,
>   0} PTOperator[id=1,name=randomGenerator]
>   RandomNumberGenerator{name=null} 2016-04-05 13:00:02,697 [main] ERROR
>   util.Shell getWinUtilsPath - Failed to locate the winutils binary in
>   the hadoop binary path java.io.IOException: Could not locate
>   executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:278)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:300)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.(Shell.java:293)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:305)

What else do I need to have installed to get a dev environment up and running? Is `Hadoop` required for JUnit tests like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it's related to "Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path"

Can you try the steps laid out?

[Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620642/failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path)