# Apache Spark can not Run on Windows

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, installation

I had downloaded **spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7** and installed it. I installed JAVA and set **JAVA_HOME** in System Variables.

But in running I have this Error:
[image]

**How to it can be fixed ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with whitespaces in your path.

Try to place downloaded spark in for example. `F:\Msc\BigData\BigDataSeminar\Spark\`

Also check whether `SPARK_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME` and `HADOOP_HOME` are placed in the path without whitespaces.

Comment: I think this is not true! because for JAVA_HOME I have `Program Files` in the path with whitespace.

Comment: Tanks! It's True. But It has another problem about `Could not locate the winutils.exe in the Hadoop binary path`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: this will help you  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620642/failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path

Comment: @SaeedRahmani It is weird because this solution usually solves this problem. If you are still having this problem you can raise a new question with description what you have/have not done.