# showing error while submitting the spark job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cmd

While i am submitting this command in cmd for my desktop
`

```
spark-submit --class retail_db.GetRevenuePerOrder “C:\Users\Lenovo\IdeaProjects\untitled\target\scala-2.11\untitled_2.11-0.1.jar”
local C:\data\retail_db\order_items C:\data\retail_db\revenue_per_order`
```

[error message ]

getting following error message

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\IdeaProjects\untitled\target\scala-2.11>spark-submit --class retail_db.GetRevenuePerOrder “C:\Users\Lenovo\IdeaProjects\untitled\target\scala-2.11\untitled_2.11-0.1.jar”
2019-04-20 17:21:07 WARN NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform… using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at retail_db.GetRevenuePerOrder$.main(GetRevenuePerOrder.scala:8)
at retail_db.GetRevenuePerOrder.main(GetRevenuePerOrder.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2019-04-20 17:21:08 INFO ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2019-04-20 17:21:08 INFO ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-2ca7c818-28cc-43e8-a71c-d53ac6c275d9

C:\Users\Lenovo\IdeaProjects\untitled\target\scala-2.11> local C:\data\retail_db\order_items C:\data\retail_db\revenue_per_order
‘local’ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Lenovo\IdeaProjects\untitled\target\scala-2.11>
```

Comment: did you setup winutil path in your environment variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620642/failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path

Comment: yes . i have setup