# Error in Pycharm when linking to pyspark: name 'spark' is not defined

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

When I run the example code in cmd, everything is ok.

```
>>> import pyspark
>>> l = [('Alice', 1)]
>>> spark.createDataFrame(l).collect()
[Row(_1='Alice', _2=1)]
```

But when I execute the code in pycharm, I get an error.

```
spark.createDataFrame(l).collect()
NameError: name 'spark' is not defined
```

Maybe something wrong when I link Pycharm to pyspark.

[Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOJE4.png)

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TclU.png)

[Project Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEoFm.png)

Comment: Are you missing the part where you define `spark`: `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession; spark=SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`? What version of spark?

Comment: spark version: 2.4.4
But in CMD, I also don't define spark.

Comment: You don't have to define those in pyspark shell - they are automatically defined for you

Answer (score 0):

When you start `pyspark` from the command line, you have a `sparkSession` object and a `sparkContext` available to you as `spark` and `sc` respectively.

For using it in pycharm, you should create these variables first so you can use them.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

#### EDIT:

Please have a look at : [Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620642/failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path)

Comment: After that, I get a new error.

`19/10/30 13:46:36 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path

java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable C:\hadoop-2.7.7\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.`

Comment: How did you install pyspark? I've never used windows, so I don't really know. Will be happy to look it up.. EDIT: I have edited my answer