# HBase client - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyProviderTokenIssuer

Tags: java, reflection, hbase, hbase-client

I'm trying to run a legacy project that connects to HBase.

It has (among other dependencies):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

When the application starts and reaches this code within the method of `createConnection` in the class of `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory`:

```
try{
    .... 
    return (Connection) constructor.newInstance(conf, managed, pool, user);
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new IOException(e);
}
```

An exception is thrown and caught, saying that:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/crypto/key/KeyProviderTokenIssuer
```

So I was looking for this class of `KeyProviderTokenIssuer` in Google but didn't find where it should come from.

Why the system is trying to use this class and where should I get it from? `Crypto` package is not part of the `hbase-client` dependency and I don't see such in https://mvnrepository.com/

Is it possible that there is some library mismatch here?

I'm running on Windows. Can it be related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to overcome this issue after performing several steps:

- Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27394808/5458827) , I downloaded the file of `hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master.zip` and fully extracted it to the folder of `C:\Program Files\apache\hadoop\bin`
- I added the `HADOOP_HOME` param to the system variables, pointing it to `C:\Program Files\apache\hadoop`
- I added to the `PATH` variable the value of `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin`
- Since my Hadoop is version 2.6.0 I checked and made sure that all Hadoop related dependencies are in that version.
- I run `mvn dependency:tree` and found that one of the dependencies jars is bringing with it the jar of `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs-client:jar:3.2.0` so I excluded it from the dependency:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>bla</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
              <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs-client</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  ```

Some URLs that helped me:

- [talend](https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/Missing-winutils-exe-Failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the/td-p/43660)
- [winutils.exe repository](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils)
- [srccodes.com](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/39/error-util-shell-failed-locate-winutils-binary-hadoop-binary-path)

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate on why did you exclude particularly `hadoop-hdfs-client`?