# java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries. spark Eclipse on windows 7

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I'm not able to run a simple `spark` job in `Scala IDE` (Maven spark project) installed on `Windows 7`

Spark core dependency has been added.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DemoDF").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val logData = sc.textFile("File.txt")
logData.count()
```

Error:

```
16/02/26 18:29:33 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at FrameDemo.scala:13
16/02/26 18:29:34 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:362)
    at <br>org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1015)
    at <br>org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at <br>org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)<br>
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getJobConf(HadoopRDD.scala:176)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:195)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)<br>
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)<br>
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)<br>
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1143)<br>
    at com.org.SparkDF.FrameDemo$.main(FrameDemo.scala:14)<br>
    at com.org.SparkDF.FrameDemo.main(FrameDemo.scala)<br>
```

Answer (score 162, accepted):

[Here](http://teknosrc.com/spark-error-java-io-ioexception-could-not-locate-executable-null-bin-winutils-exe-hadoop-binaries/) is a good explanation of your problem with the solution.

1. Download the version of winutils.exe from [https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-win-alpha/winutils.exe).
2. Set up your `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable on the OS level or programmatically:

   `System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "full path to the folder with winutils");`
3. Enjoy

Comment: I have to set HADOOP_HOME to hadoop folder instead of the bin folder.

Comment: Also, be sure to download the correct winutils.exe based on the version of hadoop that spark is compiled for (so, not necessarily the link above). Otherwise, pain awaits :)

Comment: System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop-2.7.1\\")

Comment: yes exactly as @Stanley says. worked with setting up the HADOOP_HOME to hadoop folder instead of the bin folder.

Comment: @NP3  and how do you know that version? I am using latest pyspark. Thanks,

Comment: For the correct version of *winutils.exe* checkout this [github](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils) repo. Choose the same version as the package type you choose for the Spark .tgz when you downloaded it from the official website.

Comment: The link for downloading the LATEST winutils.exe files (as of 2023) is https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/tree/master

Answer (score 79):

1. Download winutils.exe
2. Create folder, say `C:\winutils\bin`
3. Copy `winutils.exe` inside `C:\winutils\bin`
4. Set environment variable `HADOOP_HOME` to `C:\winutils`

Comment: also, if you have a cmd line open, restart it for the variables to take affect.

Comment: also add new entry to the "Path" variable as "C:\winutils\bin".

Answer (score 31):

Follow this:

1. Create a `bin` folder in any directory(to be used in step 3).
2. Download [winutils.exe](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-win-alpha/winutils.exe) and place it in the bin directory.
3. Now add `System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "PATH/TO/THE/DIR");` in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what i was looking for

Comment: It is to be noted that the path to be pointed should not include the 'bin' directory. Ex: If the path where winutils.exe is "D://Hadoop//bin//winutils.exe" , then the path for hadoop.home.dir should be "D://Hadoop"

Comment: Hi I followed the steps above, but I got `WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties` (PS: I'm using Pyspark 2.4.4 in Pycharm)

Answer (score 7):

```
1) Download winutils.exe from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils 
2) Create a directory In windows "C:\winutils\bin
3) Copy the winutils.exe inside the above bib folder .
4) Set the environmental property in the code 
  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "file:///C:/winutils/");
5) Create a folder "file:///C:/temp" and give 777 permissions.
6) Add config property in spark Session ".config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp")"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can alternatively download `winutils.exe` from GITHub:

https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin

replace `hadoop-2.7.1` with the version you want and place the file in `D:\hadoop\bin`

> If you do not have access rights to the environment variable settings
>   on your machine, simply add the below line to your code:

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\hadoop");
```

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 10 - you should add two different arguments.

(1) Add the new variable and value as - HADOOP_HOME and path (i.e. c:\Hadoop) under System Variables.

(2) Add/append new entry to the "Path" variable as "C:\Hadoop\bin".

The above worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

if we see below issue

> ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
>
> java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.

then do following steps

1. download winutils.exe from  http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-
   win-alpha/winutils.exe.
2. and keep this under bin folder of any folder you created for.e.g. C:\Hadoop\bin
3. and in program add following line before creating SparkContext or SparkConf
   System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\Hadoop");

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem while running unit tests. I found this workaround solution:

The following workaround allows to get rid of this message:

```
    File workaround = new File(".");
    System.getProperties().put("hadoop.home.dir", workaround.getAbsolutePath());
    new File("./bin").mkdirs();
    new File("./bin/winutils.exe").createNewFile();
```

from: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-544

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Hadoop_Home environment variable in system properties didn't work for me. But this did:

- Set the Hadoop_Home in the Eclipse Run Configurations environment tab.
- Follow the 'Windows Environment Setup' from [here](http://letsprog.com/apache-spark-tutorial-java-maven-eclipse/)

Answer (score 1):

- Download **winutils.exe and hadoop.dll** in your windows machine.
- create folder **C:\hadoop\bin**
- Copy winutils.exe and hadoop.dll in newly created hadoop folder
- Setup environment variable
  **HADOOP_HOME=C:\hadoop**

Answer (score 0):

On top of mentioning your environment variable for `HADOOP_HOME` in windows as `C:\winutils`, you also need to make sure you are the administrator of the machine. If not and adding environment variables prompts you for admin credentials (even under `USER` variables) then these variables will be applicable once you start your command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the similar problem with the following details Java 1.8.0_121,
Spark spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6, Windows 10 and Eclipse Oxygen.When I ran my WordCount.java in Eclipse using HADOOP_HOME as a system variable as mentioned in the previous post, it did not work, what worked for me is -

System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "PATH/TO/THE/DIR");

PATH/TO/THE/DIR/bin=winutils.exe whether you run within Eclipse as a Java application  or by spark-submit from cmd using

spark-submit --class groupid.artifactid.classname --master local[2] /path to the jar file created using maven /path
to a demo test file /path to output directory command

Example: Go to the bin location of Spark/home/location/bin and execute the spark-submit as mentioned,

D:\BigData\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-submit --class com.bigdata.abdus.sparkdemo.WordCount --master local[1] D:\BigData\spark-quickstart\target\spark-quickstart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar D:\BigData\spark-quickstart\wordcount.txt

Answer (score -1):

That's a tricky one... Your storage letter must be capical. For example "**C**:\..."