# spark-shell error on Windows - can it be ignored if not using hadoop?

Tags: apache-spark

I got the following error when starting the spark-shell. I'm going to use Spark to process data in SQL Server. Can I ignore the errors?

> java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState'
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog'
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog'
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null ls -F C:\tmp\hive
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null ls -F C:\tmp\hive
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null ls -F C:\tmp\hive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries. spark Eclipse on windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652665/java-io-ioexception-could-not-locate-executable-null-bin-winutils-exe-in-the-ha)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**tl;dr** You'd rather not.

Well, it may be *possible*, but given you've just started your journey to Spark's land the efforts would not pay off.

---

Windows has never been a developer-friendly OS to me and whenever I teach people Spark and they use Windows I just take it as granted that we'll have to go through the `winutils.exe` setup but many times also how to work on command line.

---

Please install `winutils.exe` as follows:

1. Run `cmd` as administrator
2. Download winutils.exe binary from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils repository (use [hadoop-2.7.1 for Spark 2](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/winutils.exe))
3. Save winutils.exe binary to a directory of your choice, e.g. `c:\hadoop\bin`
4. Set HADOOP_HOME to reflect the directory with winutils.exe (without `bin`), e.g. `set HADOOP_HOME=c:\hadoop`
5. Set PATH environment variable to include `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin`
6. Create `c:\tmp\hive` directory
7. Execute `winutils.exe chmod -R 777 \tmp\hive`
8. Open `spark-shell` and run `spark.range(1).show` to see a one-row dataset.

Comment: Thanks it works! Unfortunately, our IT doesn't provide Linux develop PC. These steps should be in the official documentation.