# File permission issues while running Hadoop 2.7.1

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to run my 1st Hadoop program & i'm running into file permission issues that I don't know how to resolve. Following is the error code i'm getting. Would appreciate any suggestions on debugging it. Thank you

```
779 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:Zim (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
793 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - Configuring job job_local1916101729_0001 with file:/tmp/hadoop-Zim/mapred/staging/Zim1916101729/.staging/job_local1916101729_0001 as the submit dir
793 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - adding the following namenodes' delegation tokens:[file:///]
1325 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader  - default FileSystem: file:///
1359 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO  - Initialized cache for IDs to User/Group mapping with a  cache timeout of 14400 seconds.
1363 [main] WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader  - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
1368 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - Creating splits at file:/tmp/hadoop-Zim/mapred/staging/Zim1916101729/.staging/job_local1916101729_0001
1392 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-Zim/mapred/staging/Zim1916101729/.staging/job_local1916101729_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null ls -F C:\UVic\AdvDB\Assignments\Assgn_3\assign3_hadoop_spark\hadoop_examples_post\input_weather\1901
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:659)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:634)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1733)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1713)
```

Comment: Hadoop doesn't really like being ran in Windows, in my experience

Comment: cricket is right. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808523/spark-shell-error-on-windows-can-it-be-ignored-if-not-using-hadoop) might help

Answer (score 1):

I set the HADOOP_HOME till the bin directory (C:\hadoop_spark\hadoop-2.7.1\bin). It expected me to set to C:\hadoop_spark\hadoop-2.7.1\ . Hope this helps others facing a similar problem