# How to retrieve specific limit data from file

Tags: java, file, csv

I have csv file with almost 300k records. It looks like this

```
Id, Name, City
1   Alex New York
2   Alex Florida
3   John New York
...
300k Alex New York
```

Well, I need to parse it and create 2 separate files with 500 most frequent columns(name and city). For example, in 300k records, I have 20k Alex(name), 1k John(name), 25k Fred(name) and make separate csv file with 500 most frequent names descendingly

```
Id, Name
1. Fred
2. Alex
3. John
```

The same with the cities
How to do it best?

Comment: you have to use a map of values and keep updating the map with the count of the occurrence and then after that sort that map bases on the value using comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a job for **Apache Spark**. Maybe it is a bit overkill to use such a heavy framework, but it offers elegant and scalable solution to process big data (even for relatively smaller data like 300K).

So here is one solution:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                  .master("local")
                  .appName("CSV Processor")
                  .getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
                  .option("header", "true")
                  .csv("input.csv");
df.printSchema();
Dataset<Row> grouped = df.groupBy("Name")
       .count()
       .sort(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count").desc())
       .limit(500);
grouped.show();
grouped.coalesce(1)
       .write()
       .mode("overwrite")
       .option("header", "true")
       .csv("output.csv");
```

Dependencies:

```
org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:2.1.1
org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.10:2.1.1
```

Windows cavet: [Setting winutils.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652665/java-io-ioexception-could-not-locate-executable-null-bin-winutils-exe-in-the-ha)