# Executing Pyspark on windows giving error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

To run Pyspark I have installed it through pip install pyspark. Now to initialize the session after going through many blogs I am  running below command

```
import pyspark
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
```

Above code giving me the error

> Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number

This will be my first program for spark. I want your advice on whether "pip install pyspark" is enough to run spark on my windows laptop or I need to do something else.

I have Java 8 version installed on my laptop and I am using conda with python 3.6.

Comment: No, you need to have pre-built spark present on your system and have the environment variable: SPARK_HOME set to that directory. You might also need to set HADOOP_HOME if you are doing read operations from spark. Follow this to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652665/java-io-ioexception-could-not-locate-executable-null-bin-winutils-exe-in-the-ha

Comment: I'm not convinced you actually have spark installed.  You can download it from spark.apache.org.  As Lokesh said, use the "pre-build with Hadoop" version.

Comment: Can you include the entire exception?

Comment: @16num yes you are correct I haven't installed the spark explicitly apart from pyspark. I just want to check whether pyspark commands run perfectly or not in the current environment. Even for this, I need to install spark on my laptop?

Comment: @Lokesh thanks, I will try what you have suggested first through the link and get back in case of query.