# winutils error:Error while running spark on windows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

please see below screenshots , i am getting same issue while running spark prog,can you please helpjava.io.IOException: Could not locate executable C:\hadoop\bin\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.i have added necessary paths.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries. spark Eclipse on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652665/java-io-ioexception-could-not-locate-executable-null-bin-winutils-exe-in-the-ha)

Comment: You have `bin` twice in your output. Your HADOOP_HOME variable should not have bin in it

Comment: i already made the change but thankyou

Comment: If you've made the changes to remove the second `bin`, then [edit] the post with the new error, as text, not an image

Answer (score 1):

Add this comments in your program

downloaded the winutils.exe and placed it in C:/Bin/Winutils.exe

then added the following line to my project at the start of the function

```
 System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutil\\")
```

Comment: in mycase i have to use "C:\\hadoop\\"