# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Tags: java, hadoop

trying to run MR program version(2.7) in windows 7 64 bit in eclipse while running the above exception occurring .
  I verified that using 64 bit 1.8 java version and observed that all the hadoop daemons are running.

Any suggestions highly appreciated

Comment: It seems that java unable to find any native library. May be any dll file is corrupted or not accessible by java program.

Comment: There is a similar issue , you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630019/running-apache-hadoop-2-1-0-on-windows

Comment: in that case while starting daemons this problem occurring .but in my case no issues while starting but while executing map reduce program that exception occurring

Comment: It seems any native library that is required for map reduce program is not accessible. Please share stack trace for more information.

Answer (score 66):

In addition to other solutions, Please download **winutil.exe** and **hadoop.dll** and add to $HADOOP_HOME/bin. It works for me.

https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin

**Note: I'm using hadoop-2.7.3 version**
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have encountered the same problem while starting Namenode. Iam unable to start Namenode. Please help

Comment: Iam using Hadoop-3.0.0. I had downloaded hadoop.dll and winutils.exe from the Github link you had provided. But still no luck. It throws the same error while starting Namenode

Comment: The link above doesn't have 3.1.1. (yet?). Found this one that seems to be working for the newest version: https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils

Comment: @JonAndrews - were you able to sort it out at the end? Having the same issue, the same hadoop version... Thanks!

Comment: I am using hadoop 3.3.0 and spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3. Still I am getting error. Can anyone help me on this

Comment: it works for me (spark 3.3.1)

Comment: Nothing worked until I restarted the computer. I didn't understand what it changed, but the error disappeared. Maybe it will help someone

Answer (score 58):

After putting `hadoop.dll` and `winutils` in `hadoop/bin` folder and adding the folder of hadoop to `PATH`, we also need to put `hadoop.dll` into the `C:\Windows\System32` folder

Comment: Have done this but the error still pop up. Any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't needed the `C:\Windows\System32` step. `WinUntils.exe` and `hadoop.dll` in the Hadoop bin folders did it for me. The environment variable and path setting are critical though.

Comment: @Dan Dunno why, but putting hadoop.dll into the C:\Windows\System32 folder was critical for me as well.

Comment: @diman82 Did you have the environment variable `HADOOP_HOME` and path set-up and restarted? (Not critical, things are running for you; I'm simply curious what's causing the difference).

Comment: No need to put hadoop.dll to C:\Windows\System32. It should work if you have hadoop.dll in your Path variable. When you put it into System32 it will be definitely in Path.

Answer (score 29):

This issue occurred to me and the cause was I forgot to append `%HADOOP_HOME%/bin` to `PATH` in my environment variables.

Comment: It's worth noting that the ``HADOOP_HOME`` user or system variable has to be created first before the above can be added to the ``PATH``. Typically, ``HADOOP_HOME`` would point to where your hadoop is installed such as ``C:\hadoop-2.8.1``. And as always with changing the ``PATH`` variable, a restart is usually required.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I was having this issue when running unit tests on local machine after upgrading dependencies to `CDH6`. I already had `HADOOP_HOME` and `PATH` variables configured properly but I had to copy the `hadoop.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32` as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 7):

After trying all the above, things worked after putting hadoop.dll to windows/System32

Answer (score 4):

For me this issue was resolved by downloading the winutils.exe & hadoop.dll from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin  and putting those in hadoop/bin folder

Answer (score 4):

Adding hadoop.dll and WinUntils.exe fixed the error, support for latest versions can be found [here](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I already had `%HADOOP_HOME%/bin` in my `PATH` and my code had previously run without errors. Restarting my machine made it work again.

Answer (score 2):

The version mismacth is main cause for this issue. Follow complete hadoop version with java library will solve the issue and if you still face issue and working on hadoop 3.1.x version use this library to download bin

`https://github.com/s911415/apache-hadoop-3.1.0-winutils/tree/master/bin`

Answer (score 1):

I already had `%HADOOP_HOME%/bin` in my PATH. Adding [hadoop.dll](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-3.2.2/bin/hadoop.dll) in `Hadoop/bin directory` made it work again.

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij under Run/Debug Configurations, open the application you are trying to run, Under configurations tab, specify the exact working Directory.having the variable to represent the working directory also creates this problem. When I changed the Working Directory under configurations, it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this issues arose when I was using the `PIGUNITS` for automation of `PIGSCRIPTS`.  Two things in sequence need to be done:

1. Copy both the files as mentioned about in a location and add it to the environment variables under PATH.
2. To reflect the change what you have just done, you have to restart your machine to load the file.

Under JUNIT I was getting this error which would help others as well:

> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias XXXXX. Backend error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:925)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: Download the latest winutils https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils Or check your spark Release text, it shows the cer of Hadoop it is using

Steps

1. Dowload repo
2. Create a folder named hadoop anywhere (e.g. desktop/hadoop)
3. Paste the bin into that folder (you will then have hadoop/bin)
4. copy hadoop.dll to windows/system32
5. Set system environment:

   ```
   set HADOOP_HOME=c:/desktop/hadoop 
   set PATH=%PATH%;%HADOOP_HOME%/bin;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have to download the winutils from https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils as it has the latest version 3.3.

It is important to make sure the version matches to the Hadoop version you downloaded (with or without Spark) otherwise, you can find some weird error messages.

Both hadoop.dll and winutils.exe are fine to be at the same folder C:/hadoop/bin. I didn't copy either to system folder and it works.

Note: I followed [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-windows-10) except the download pages of winutils tool.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading and configuring hadoop.dll and wintuils.exe as previous answer, you need to "restart the windows" to make it works.

Comment: 1) Download from where? What is there to "configure"? 2) You should only need to edit your PATH and restart the terminal, not the whole OS

Answer (score 0):

In my case (**pyspark = 3.3.1, Spark version = 3.3.1, Hadoop version = 3.3.2**)
I set env vars by python code

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Hadoop\\"
```

added from https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils to bin folder last version of hadoop files **hadoop-3.4.0-win10-x64** and added **hadoop.dll** to **C:\Windows\System32**

Comment: You should be using the 3.3.2 winutils, since that's what you have installed, not a version of it for an unreleased Hadoop version

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spark version 3.1.2 and hadoop 3.2 (spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2).

I solved this by just downloading the hadoop.dll file from a Github page = https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils
and saving it to the bin folder within my spark folder. Then  spark-submit went smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas all the above recommendations failed to resolve this error for me. Setting the environment variable HADOOP_BIN_PATH resolved the error for me. Also another related error where the word access0 in the error string is replaced with [createDirectoryWithMode0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282184/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io-nativeio-nativeiowindows-c).

If you look in the hadoop/bin folder and inspect hdfs.cmd and mapred.cmd it is clear that the HADOOP_BIN_PATH environment variable is expected. For example this code:

```
if not defined HADOOP_BIN_PATH ( 
  set HADOOP_BIN_PATH=%~dp0
)
```

%~dp0 should expand to the folder containing the cmd file. However, you could imagine other components of hadoop such as the daemons that do not start from the command line which may also expect this environment variable to be set.

Set HADOOP_BIN_PATH to the bin folder under your hadoop directory.

If you set a user environment variable you will need to restart the process running your application. If you set a system environment variable you will need to restart Windows to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue still persists after adding the correct version of hadoop winutils + hadoop.dll, check if you have installed JRE or JDK.

Hadoop is written in Java. So it would require JRE (Java Runtime Environment) at the very least with the supported version. But JRE (Java Runtime Environment) is insufficient.
For running Map-Reduce jobs, Hadoop essentially requires JDK (Java Development Kit). This is why after installation (with JRE), when you run the command `pyspark` in the terminal, you get this `Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform` warning.
For me, switching to JDK resolved these issues.

Here's a thread on JDK requirement for Hadoop: https://www.quora.com/Why-we-need-JDK-for-Hadoop-installation

Answer (score -1):

This might be old but if its still not working for someone, Step 1- Double click on winutils.exe. If it shows some dll file is missing, download that .dll file and place that at appropriate place.

In my case, msvcr100.dll wasmissing and I had to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package to make it work.
All the best

Comment: That exe file isn't meant to be "double clicked".