# HBaseTestingUtility failing on Windows 10 with UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to get the `HBaseTestingUtility` running on Windows 10.

I'm using `hbase-client` and `hbase-testing-util` with version `1.4.2`.

When running:

```
HBaseTestingUtility hbaseUtility = new HBaseTestingUtility();
hbaseUtility.startMiniCluster(); //<- error thrown on this line
```

I get the below error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:609)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canWrite(FileUtil.java:996)
...
```

I have downloaded [winutils](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.8.3), and have set the following user variables:

```
hadoop.home.dir=C:\Users\bwatson\apps\hadoop-2.8.3
HADOOP_HOME=C:\Users\bwatson\apps\hadoop-2.8.3
```

but this does not make a difference.

The official documentation for the `HBaseTestingUtility` says that [Cygwin is needed on Windows](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/_chapters/unit_testing.adoc), but I cannot install that due to the admin restrictions on my work machine. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found a solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43484457/729819. I `%HADOOP_HOME%/bin` to PATH. Now I get another error but will raise another question for that.