# MiniDFSCluster UnsatisfiedLinkError org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hdfs, junit5

When doing:

```
new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(config).build()
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:557)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canWrite(FileUtil.java:996)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:490)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:308)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:202)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1020)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:739)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:536)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:595)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:762)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:746)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.createNameNode(MiniDFSCluster.java:1107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.createNameNodesAndSetConf(MiniDFSCluster.java:978)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.initMiniDFSCluster(MiniDFSCluster.java:807)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:467)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster$Builder.build(MiniDFSCluster.java:426)
```

I want to use the Hadoop Minicluster to test my Hadoop HDFS (which does not throw this exception, see [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282184/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io-nativeio-nativeiowindows-c)).

In my Maven pom.xml I have these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for unit testing -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for unit testing -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I understood, I do not need to the specific 'hadoop-minicluster' dependency as it already comes with the above included hadoop-hdfs.

I am trying to build the MiniDFSCluster in my @BeforeAll.

I have used different configs for the builder:

```
config = new HdfsConfiguration(); / config = new Configuration();
```

And different ways to create a path for the baseDir:

```
config.set(miniDfsClusterHD.HDFS_MINIDFS_BASEDIR, baseDir);
```

Also, I downloaded the hadoop.dll and hdfs.dll and winuntils.exe in v2.6.0 and added the path to those in my environment variables.

I studied all the related issues I could find in stackoverflow (without success, obviously) and all guides and code examples I could find in the internet (there are a few and they all do it differently.)

Can somehow please help me, I am out of ideas.

UPDATE:

I am running the test with the following VM options (which should not be necessary, I think):

-Dhadoop.home.dir=C:/Temp/hadoop
-Djava.library.path=C:/Temp/hadoop/bin

I also tried to set the environment variables directly (which should not be necessary when using the VM options):

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\Temp\\hadoop-2.6.0");
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\Temp\\hadoop-2.6.0\\bin");
```

Comment: Same issue here. Were you able to fix it ?

Comment: No I did not, I think :-/

Comment: What I've noticed in my case is that setting the following VM option : _-Djava.library.path=C:/Temp/hadoop/bin_ solves the issue when running test with IntelliJ's runner. It does not when using _mvn test_ though

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by downloading the source file (org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.java) and modifying line in
function access (in your case 557) from:

```
return access0(path, desiredAccess.accessRight());
```

to

```
return true;
```