# why not able to write sparkdataframe into parquet file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to write spark dataframe into parquet file but not able to write dataframe into parquet even i tried with csv

df is my dataframe

```
CUST_ID
---------------
00000082MM778Q49X
00000372QM8890MX7
00000424M09X729MQ
0000062Q028M05MX
```

my dataframe looks as above

```
df_parquet = (tempDir+"/"+"df.parquet") #filepath

customerQuery = f"SELECT DISTINCT(m.customer_ID) FROM ada_customer m INNER JOIN customer_nol mr ON m.customer_ID = mr.customer_ID \
WHERE mr.MODEL <> 'X' and m.STATUS = 'Process' AND m.YEAR = {year} AND mr.YEAR = {year}"

customer_df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbkl",
                                                    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                                                    query=customerQuery, user="root", password="root").load()

# above lines are working only writing into file not working

customer_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(df_parquet)
```

i'm getting this error don't know exactly what's wrong. can some one help with this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/SparkBook/HG.py", line 135, in <module>
    customer_xdf.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(customer_parquet)
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1372, in csv
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:220)
    ... 33 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/SparkBook/HG.py", line 148, in <module>
    logger.error(e)
  File "F:\SparkBook\lib\logger.py", line 16, in error
    self.logger.error(message)
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1296, in __call__
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1266, in _build_args
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1266, in <listcomp>
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 298, in get_command_part
AttributeError: 'Py4JJavaError' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: how does df_parquet look like?

Comment: @RobertKossendey please check i have updated

Comment: So you can confirm that df_parquet is of type string and df is of type DataFrame, right?

Comment: @RobertKossendey yes

Comment: Could you provide the whole script please?

Comment: @RobertKossendey I can't provide whole script but I  have updated the part which is required please check

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851066/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io

Comment: @MohanaBC it didn't work

Comment: looks like you're using `dir` keyword in the `df_parquet` path. Can you try using another variable name?

Comment: @pltc  actually somepart of  the keyword is removed before posting. no problem with the path