# Unable to read file in spark program from local directory

Tags: apache-spark

I am unable to read the local csv file in spark program. I am using PyCharm IDE. Although I am able to use the position argument to read the file but not with file location. Can someone please help?

```
// code
    # Processing logic here...
    flightTimeCsvDF = spark.read \
        .format("csv") \
        .option("header", "true") \
        .load("data/flight*.csv")
        # .load(sys.argv[1])


\\error
Exception in thread "globPath-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.listStatus(Globber.java:128)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdsXB.png)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851066/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io) should help you out!

Answer (score 1):

Please use the absolute path. From the image attached, I believe using the following will help solve the issue.

```
.load("C:\\Users\\psultania\\Anaconda3\\envs\\04-SparkSchemaDemo\\data\\flight*.csv")
```

If you are using different directories for input CSVs, please change the directory definition accordingly.

Comment: For me issue resolved by giving file name without regex ,  path can be relative. Followed solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76098850/spark-code-to-read-a-set-of-csv-giving-javalink-error

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this answer worked for me.
Originally, I had parameterized the data directory, file pattern, and the file format. But, the execution ran into the same error as the OP shown above. After removing those parameters and just passing the fully qualified file path to the load method worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Yes it works using absolute path