# Spark code to read a set of csv giving javalink error

Tags: pyspark

I have a set of CSV files inside a sub-directory (donation). I tried to read the csv and create a DataFrame.

spark.read.csv("donation/block*.csv").

But I am getting the following error.

Exception in thread "globPath-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting this error on windows ?
I was facing the similar issue on windows, I tried multiple things but nothing was working.
Thing that worked for me was to not have any regex pattern in the file name.
Give complete name of your file along with it's absolute path.
For example instead of

```
spark.read.csv("donation/block*.csv")
```

Use

```
spark.read.csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\donation\\block123.csv")
```

If you want to read multiple files together you can pass multiple paths
For example

```
spark.read.csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\donation\\block123.csv","C:\\Users\\Desktop\\donation\\block123.csv")
```

Please Note: I'm assuming that you're using spark on windows for just adhoc analysis or debugging because windows is not the ideal platform to run the spark jobs.