# Exporting MySQL table to CSV format using PySpark results in Job Aborted Exception

Tags: python, apache-spark, export-to-csv

I am using spark to read a mysql table under the window, and then save it in the D disk in csv format. keep reporting error.

I am trying to write a dataframe to csv and store it in local. But I am facing issue when writing to CSV as

I modified the scala version to be consistent with spark_shell (2.13.8)

```
import os
import sys
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = sys.executable
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = sys.executable
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Export to CSV").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
    url=mysql_url,
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    dbtable=table_name,
    user=username,
    password=password).load()

df.show(10)

df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").option("compression", "uncompressed").save("D:/logs/a")
```

error

```
Py4JJavaError
An error occurred while calling o40.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:651)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$26(FileFormatWriter.scala:277)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:277)
    ... 41 more
  File "D:\GIT\python\测试 copy.py", line 31, in <module>
    df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").option("compression", "uncompressed").save("D:/logs/a")
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:651)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$26(FileFormatWriter.scala:277)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:277)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: The real error is `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z` . Googling for that returns a number of other questions on SO, including https://stackoverflow.com/q/41851066 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/74686910 .

Comment: writing a dataframe to a csv is very easy in python.   `df.to_csv(''file_name.csv")`  ....  so the dataframe is not the issue here (as per the error message).

Comment: I have solved this problem, after adding the hadoop.dll , thank you