"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)' i
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)
when trying to execute the spark scala writing into parquet format. i have set up hadoop home in environment set up.
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scala.version>2.12.18</scala.version>
        <jackson.version>2.15.2</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-spark_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
            <artifactId>parquet-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hadoop Client API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


Seems like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74686910/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io
