# error using miniDFSCluster on windows

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

I'm trying to write unit tests using miniDFSCluster and it's throwing the error below

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

any pointers to resolve this issue?

Comment: http://qnalist.com/questions/4416644/mvn-eclipse-eclipse-failure-on-windows might be a helpful discussion for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this error by following these steps:

1. Download `hadoop.dll` and `winutils.exe` in the **same version** that I'm using in the sbt/maven configuration, you can find these files in all versions of hadoop here: [link](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils)
2. Put these 2 files in your `%hadoop directory%\bin` folder
3. make sure that `%hadoop directory%\bin` is listed under `PATH` in your device's environmental path(if using windows)

then the code should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

With errors like this, I use three steps

1. Find out what it is looking for

   ```
        In this case, *org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0*
   ```
2. Find out what jar/lib it is in.

   ```
        I don't use the Windows version, but I believe it is in hadoop.dll - 
        you'll have to check this.
   ```
3. Find out where I'm telling it to use that jar/lib

Update:  See also this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630019/running-apache-hadoop-2-1-0-on-windows).