# ERROR util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path in Windows 10

Tags: apache, hadoop, nutch

Can anyone please help me how to configure nutch in eclipse. I tried all the tutorial available in the wiki .(http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial, and many others as I am not able to paste all the links here). But everytime I am getting a NullPointerException. Is there any other tutorial available for the same.

But in My hadoop.log I found this message
**ERROR util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path.**

I am using hadoop-2.5.2 but this package does not contain any winutils.exe .  I also tried other tutorials available to build Winutils.exe using VisualStudio but unable to create it.

Please help me how to create winutils.exe using Visual Studio 2015, I think without winutils.exe I cant run Nutch.

Note: I am using Windows 10 , Visual Studio 2015, hadoop-2.5.2, Apache Nutch 2.x

After putting the winutils.exe available in another link, Now I am getting a new Error
**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620642/failed-to-locate-the-winutils-binary-in-the-hadoop-binary-path)

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2356

Comment: Yes I tried the above link but that does not work for me. It is now throwing java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630019/running-apache-hadoop-2-1-0-on-windows

Comment: I also tried with solution provided in the link, but Still i am getting the same linking error. That's why I have mentioned all the environment I am working.

Comment: what is the other error you get ?

Comment: I am getting the same "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z" error. And aslo when I tried with VC++ I am getting error in building the project, even there is no option to upgrade the project, as my winutils.sln is VC2010  compatible. And I am using VC2015, do I need to install VC2010 ??

Comment: Yes I tried with the winutils.exe provided in the above link and surprisingly it is working in Windows 7 but not in Windows 10.

Comment: Did you try building the winutils.exe for your Windows? Since, it is a .exe file it varies for different platforms.

Comment: yeah Harman I tried but Visual Studio is unable to build the project , it throws many error and   I am unable to fix that thing.

Comment: Which Hadoop distro are you using?

Comment: hadoop-2.5.2.src.tar.gz

Comment: Apache distro or CDH or HDP?

Comment: it is Apache distro.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Hadoop wiki page to setup on Winows](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows), Apache Hadoop has been tested and used on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2, which will also likely work on Windows Vista and Windows 7 due to the Win32 API similarities.

This said, you have 3 options:

1. You can go in for a Hadoop distribution which supports Windows 10.
2. You can opt for a different Windows version which is supported by the distribution you choose.
3. The one I would recommend, go in for a Linux (preferably CentOS,RedHat,etc.) based machine if possible. And then you have a whole lot of distributions to choose from.

In case, you find a solution to the issue you're facing I would encourage you to answer your question yourself :)