# Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to Hadoop i have downloaded hadoop tar file and did set up for my windows personal laptop. i am able to create directory in C drive with `hdfs dfs -mkdir /testDirHadoop2` command, i am also able to create a file in that directory using `hdfs dfs -touchz /testDirHadoop2/test.txt` this command. But when i try to run `hdfs dfs -ls /testDirHadoop2` it is trowing below error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Can some one please help me get rid of this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27394749/3238085 : did you try answers mentioned elsewhere ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Apache Hadoop 2.1.0 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630019/running-apache-hadoop-2-1-0-on-windows)

Answer (score -2):

1. Make sure you have the hadoop dll in your System32 folder
2. Make sure you have HADOOP_HOME set to a folder that contains winutils.exe
3. See answer here: [Apache nutch 1.15 installing and running issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56909495/782117)