# Upgrading hadoop from 2.10.2 to 3.3.4 - got "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I was updating hadoop version from 2.10.1 to 3.3.4 in my maven pom file and got this error message-

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
```

I referred previous question on stack-overflow and added hadoop.dll to hadoop environment variable's path still got same error message, then I add it to System32 directory, and it starts working. I just wanted to know if someone know why we need to do this ?
for 2.10.1 I haven't added hadoop.dll, I just had winutils.exe (2.7.2) in my HDOOP_HOME/bin path

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a winutils + hadoop.dll file that are compiled for Hadoop 3.3.4 (and/or 3.3.5, if you want to upgrade to that). Versions are not cross-compatible. Even 2.7.2 should not have worked for 2.10.1