# FTP vs SFTP vs HDFS vs NTFS vs EXT2, EXT3

Tags: linux, ftp, hdfs, sftp, ext2

I just want to know how these protocols and file systems are related with each other, where each one is used.

FTP vs SFTP vs HDFS vs NTFS vs EXT2, EXT3

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftp

Comment: Protocols and filesystems aren't related to each other at all. Filesystems are a way of storing data, protocols are a way of accessing filesystems over the network.

Comment: Regarding the close reason explanation...I suggest that you ask a clearer and more specific question before you post this as [su], or you probably won't get much help over there either. This is way too broad and open-ended. It sounds more like a topic for a Google search than for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP is an old File Transfer Protocol, similar to HTTP but specialized for moving large files.

sftp is a totally different protocol. It is tunneled over ssh and is therefore encrypted.

HDFS is the Hadoop distributed filesystem. It is designed to hold many petabytes of data in a single filesystem image.

NTFS, ext2, and ext3 are operating system specific disk filesystems. NTFS is the primary filesystem on most Windows computers. ext2 used to be the de-facto Linux filesystem and has since been replaced by ext3 and now ext4. All of the ext filesystems are related and you can upgrade from ext2 -> ext3 -> ext4 in place.

Comment: thanks @tobert. they say you cannot transfer a file from a ftp server directly to a hadoop server. like if i run "ftp" on a regular linux server it runs, but on hadoop HDFS, it says invalid command. any light on this ?

Comment: HDFS is not a "real" filesystem in that it is not accessible through the normal operating system tools. That is why commands like 'ls' are 'hadoop ls'.

If you want to FTP a file into HDFS, you will need to download it to a staging area, then load it into HDFS with 'hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal'
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyFromLocal